# How can someone claim themselves as a dependent?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, tax-exemption, form-1040x

I'm filing my taxes on a 1040A form and I noticed this line

[image]

No one is claiming me as a dependent, so does that mean I should count myself as an exemption? What would that even mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it means you can (and, usually, should) claim an exemption for yourself *as long as* no one else can claim you as a dependent. You're not claiming that you are your own dependent; you are claiming your personal exemption (if you can).

Ultimately, you are claiming exemptions. You get to claim an exemption for yourself *if* no one else can claim you as a dependent. You also get to claim an exemption for each of your own dependents, if any.